# An upper bound to this fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following is an expression I am trying to upper bound by a constant

$$I=\frac{x}{1+2y}\leq \ ?$$

The condition that I am using is  $$ 2 x < y $$

I have tried the following $$ I = \frac{x}{1+2y} \leq \frac{4x}{2y}\leq 1 $$

But it seems that this is a very loose bound. Can anyone find a better one?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variables are positive, then replacing $x$ by $y/2$ gives the upper bound $(y/2)/(1+2y),$ which is at most $1/4.$ (it is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ with asymptote at $y=1/4.$)